# Light switch issue...what to do?

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I was working on replacing some bathroom switches to a more modern single pole.  I got the new switch wired and switch and fan work great but my hall light and dining room light have no power...there are 2 extra wires in the box which seem to control these switches??  What to do with them to make everything work again?  Circled in blue are the extra wires

[image]

Comment: Can you upload pictures showing the existing wires? If you have any *before* pictures that would help a lot...and if you don't, in the future always take pictures before disconnecting any wires.

Comment: Where were those " extra " wires before you took everything apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a wire nut and connect them to the wire circled in yellow.

[image: wire nut here]

Comment: And a pig tail to feed the switch in the picture I assume?

Comment: Yup.  I'm sure they were stabbed in or doubled up on screws on the switches.

Comment: Must have been...! We've light again! Thanks